# FXMLLLoader cannot be resolved

Tags: javafx

I am creating a calculator in JavaFX but Eclipse displays the following error message: FXMLLLoader can not be resolved. I do not know which library I should import so that eclipse recognizes the FXMLLLoader class. Here's the code I made.

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLLoader.load(getClass().getClass().getResource("/application/Main.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene((javafx.scene.Parent) root, 400, 400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

FXMLLLoader:[image]

Comment: Try fixing the typo and remove one of the `L`-s as in `FXMLLoader` -- if that doesn't help, try to see if there are other people who cannot load a module. :)

Comment: Corrected typos but still the error continues. Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/Main.fxml"));

Comment: Edit the question to include your corrected version of the code. Also include the imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have too many "L"s when you try to use the FXMLLoader. You also need to make sure you import the FXML Loader library:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
```

Comment: No problem, keep it up, it's always a great feeling to see your code turn into something awesome!!